# Quick run code app for Linux

Tags: linux, java, php, python, ide

On Mac OS I am using [CodeRunner](https://coderunnerapp.com/) for snippets and API methods quick testing (you don't need to create project etc., just selecting language and write/test code). Is something similar available for Linux?

I want to run Java code (classes), Python, PHP with single click and without creating/saving files every time. Is it possible on Linux?

Comment: Sounds like you want a text editor with the built-in ability to run your code. For python and PHP at least they also have interactive modes (`php -a`) and `python` that allow you to execute your code and receive instant output.

Answer (score 1):

[iPython](http://ipython.org/) has always provided an interactive environment that will let you execute your code python directly.  For quite some time there have also been a QT console and iPython notebooks.

From version 3.0 onwards [iPython](http://ipython.org/) has provided "magic's" for embedding code in Cython, R, Octave, Javascript, Bash, Perl or Ruby - *(all assuming that you have them installed on your system*.

There is currently a move to shift the cross language side over to a new project called [Jupyter](https://jupyter.org/) which will integrate the back ends and be more language agnostic but for the moment I would have a play with iPython.